# Group by 3 different counts from 3 different tables on a field from a 4th table

Tags: sql, count, group-by

With these tables:

```
Table name:      Fields:
Users            userID
F                fID,userID
B                total,userID,bID
L                lID,bID
```

Users.userID is the "key", and its relation to the other tables are:

F.userID is the same as Users.userID 
B.userID is the same as Users.userID 
L.bID is the same as B.bID

I need, for each Users.userID - to show: 
a count of fID for that userID in F, 
a sum of all 'total's for that userID in B 
a count for all lID with bID from B that is in L.

(It's gonna be clearer after looking at the query below:)

I tried this:

```
SELECT Users.userID, COUNT(F.fID) as 'fcount', SUM(B.total) as 'bcount', COUNT(L.lID) as 'lcount' 
FROM Users
    JOIN F ON F.userID=Users.userID
    JOIN B ON B.userID=Users.userID
    JOIN L ON L.bID=B.bID
GROUP BY Users.userID
```

Now, the 'count' columns display unreasonably high numbers, which don't reflect what I'm hoping to get, and I don't know where they're coming from (and don't need to, just need to know how to get the right counts :) ).

Thank you.

Comment: If you have duplicate `F.fID` do you only want to count once per unique value? You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT F.fID)` if that's the case. Although it's possibly you may be missing a join if the numbers are really high.

Comment: It's probably high from the `JOIN`s - if you have multiple occurences of any of the join keys in any of the affected tables, your counts will be inflated.

Comment: I have duplicate F.fID - and I need to count all of them (all of the fIDs for each F.userID=Users.userID. But your comment helped, I did need to use DISTINCT for the SUM part, this part now returns the right numbers. The other two still don't though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join repeats each matching row on the right side for each row on the left side.  If you join more than one table, rows get repeated more.

For example, say a customer has five orders and two addresses.  Then the following query will return 1 x 5 x 2 = 10 rows:

```
select  *
from    Customer c
join    [Order] o
on      o.CustomerID = c.ID
join    Address a
on      a.CustomerID = c.ID
where   c.ID = 42
```

If you'd calculate an order total over this rowset, you'd get twice the amount, because each order is repeated for each address.

This is typically solved with subqueries that are guaranteed to return only one row per group:

```
select  u.userID
,       fcount
,       bcount
,       lcount
from    Users u
join    (
        select  UserID
        ,       count(*) as fcount
        from    F
        group by
                UserID
        ) F
on      F.UserID = u.UserID
join    (
        select  UserID
        ,       sum(*) bcount
        from    B
        group by
                UserID
        ) B
on      B.UserID = u.UserID
join    (
        select  B.UserID
        ,       count(*) lcount
        from    B
        join    L
        on      L.bID = B.bID
        group by
                B.UserID
        ) L
on      L.UserID = u.UserID
```